# Input are not able to calculate and print out in C

Tags: c

I've tried to build a simple calculator for physics force experiments.

```
//
//  main.c

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char name[20];
    int  month,date;
    int difference_percentage1, difference_percentage2, difference_percentage3;
    double force1, force2, force3;
    scanf("%s", name);
    scanf("%d %d", &month, &date);
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &force1, &force2, &force3);
    double Favg=(force1 + force2 + force3)/3.000;
    puts(name);
    difference_percentage1=100*(force1-Favg)/Favg;
    difference_percentage2=100*(force2-Favg)/Favg;
    difference_percentage3=100*(force3-Favg)/Favg;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", difference_percentage1, difference_percentage2, difference_percentage3);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The calculate doesn't match what I've typed for `scanf()`.

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a image

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: My guess is that the `%f` that is showing is not actually what it appears.  Perhaps provide a hex dump of the line.  Also, the double argument should be paired with `%lf` rather than `%f`, but that doesn't explain the warning that your compiler is showing.

Comment: `/3.000;` can be `/3.0;` or even `/3;` will work because other variables are double.

Comment: In that line with the warning, you can see that there are 2 different characters `'%'` in your format string. I assume the first one uses some incorrect character encoding that is not recognized by `printf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The o's of the % mark for the %f look a bit larger to me than for the %d, so my guess is that you used the wrong % for the %f format specifier which isn't recognized by the compiler; it interprets the double value as int.

Edit: one more reason to post text instead of a screenshot of the code! (o;

Edit2: Yup, your % mark in %f is actually a "EF BC 85" in hex but should be "25"

Comment: @annazxc: Great! Please accept the answer so this is marked as solved.